# discord.py :: How can I get my bot to react to it's own message?

Tags: python, discord.py

Under my on_message I have this;

```
 if message.channel.id == 809991898722861137:
        emoji = client.get_emoji(830070201885130823)
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        emoji = client.get_emoji(830070201722601523)
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        emoji = client.get_emoji(830070202091175976)
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        emoji = client.get_emoji(830070201654837249)
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

But whenever I do a command to make my bot send a message, the reactions are only posted on my message, not my bots.

Is there a way I can do this so the reactions will be on my bots message as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the reaction to be on both your message and the bot's message.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 809991898722861137:
        emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}' # Thumbs up emoji
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Or, if you want the reaction to be only on the bot:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 809991898722861137:
        if message.author == client.user: # Check if the message came from the bot
            emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}' # Thumbs up emoji
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        else:
            # Do something else
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I tried the top code that you listed as an example, but unfortunately it still isn't reacting to it's own message. Instead when I do the command for the bot to send a message, it's now sending the message twice.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: I'm not sure about the cause to why it repeats the message, I'm sorry. What's odd is that the code works on my end... can you try adding `if message.author != client.user or message.author == client.user:` after `if message.channel.id == 809991898722861137:`? I tried this and got the same result on my end.